# bullet in table not aligned

Tags: tables, bullets

I created the following table. however, the bullets are not aligned. What can I do to get them aligned?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Symbolic Math Toolbox}
\begin{itemize}
\item Don't do nasty calculations by hand!
\item Symbolics vs. Numerics
\end{itemize}
\begin{tabular}{| p{1.3cm} | p{4cm} | p{4cm} |} \hline    & \textcolor{green}{Advantages} & \textcolor{red}{Disadvantages} \\ \hline
Symbolic & \tabitem Analytical solutions & \tabitem Sometimes can't be solved \\
 & \tabitem Lets you intuit things about solution form & \tabitem Can be overly complicated \\ \hline 
Numeric & \tabitem Always get a solution & \tabitem Hard to extract a deep understanding \\
 &\tabitem Can make solutions accurate & \tabitem Num. methods sometimes fail \\  
 & \tabitem Easy to code & \tabitem Can take a while to compute \\  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
\newcommand\tabitem{\makebox[1em][r]{\textbullet~}}
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer is similar in spirit to the one by @daleif. The difference is that I use the macro `\RaggedRight` (from the `ragged2e` package) instead of the basic `\raggedright` directive; the difference is that `\RaggedRight` permits hyphenation. I also use a `\newcolumntype` instruction to set up a new column type called "P" that sets in contents automatically in Ragged-Right paragraph mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\textbullet~~}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Symbolic Math Toolbox}
\begin{itemize}
\item Don't do nasty calculations by hand!
\item Symbolics vs.\ Numerics
\end{itemize}
\begin{tabular}{| p{1.4cm} | P{4cm} | P{4cm} |} \hline    
& \textcolor{green}{Advantages} 
& \textcolor{red}{Disadvantages} \\ \hline
Symbolic 
& \tabitem Analytical solutions 
& \tabitem Sometimes can't be solved \\
& \tabitem Lets you intuit things about solution form 
& \tabitem Can be overly complicated \\ \hline 
Numeric 
& \tabitem Always get a solution 
& \tabitem Hard to extract a deep understanding \\
& \tabitem Can make solutions accurate 
& \tabitem Num.\ methods sometimes fail \\  
& \tabitem Easy to code 
& \tabitem Can take a while to compute \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that is a better solution

Answer (score 3):

Presumably because `~` is stretchable and your columns are attempting to to keep a straight right edge.

Probably better to use

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Symbolic Math Toolbox}
\begin{itemize}
\item Don't do nasty calculations by hand!
\item Symbolics vs. Numerics
\end{itemize}
\begin{tabular}{| >{\raggedright}p{1.3cm} | >{\raggedright}p{4cm} | 
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm} |} \hline &
  \textcolor{green}{Advantages} & \textcolor{red}{Disadvantages}
  \\
  \hline Symbolic & \tabitem Analytical solutions & \tabitem Sometimes
  can't be solved
  \\
  & \tabitem Lets you intuit things about solution form & \tabitem Can
  be overly complicated
  \\
  \hline Numeric & \tabitem Always get a solution & \tabitem Hard to
  extract a deep understanding
  \\
  & \tabitem Can make solutions accurate & \tabitem Num. methods
  sometimes fail
  \\
  & \tabitem Easy to code & \tabitem Can take a while to compute
  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and thus setting the cols ragged right. Note the `\arraybackslash` added to the last column.

Comment: BTW: Micos solution using `\RaggedRight` is probably better

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with a `tabitem` environment, which actually is an `itemize` environment and so also takes care of the indention after a linebreak.

Unfortunately it seems that the `array` packages causes a spurious extra line at the end of the `tabitem` environment, so I haven't loaded this package and therefore also not the `ragged2e` package.

I want to point out that the definiton of this environment is not from me. I think I have it almost 10 years now, but cannot remember where I grabbed it from. I somebody knows, please raise the hand and I will add the source here.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
%    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{booktabs}
    \newenvironment{tabitem}{%
        \vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}%
        \setdefaultitem{\normalfont\bfseries\textbullet}%
            {\normalfont\bfseries\textendash}{}{}%
        \setdefaultleftmargin{1.1em}{1.1em}{}{}{}{}%
        \begin{compactitem}%
    }{%
        \end{compactitem}%
        \vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Symbolic Math Toolbox}
\begin{itemize}
\item Don't do nasty calculations by hand!
\item Symbolics vs.\ Numerics
\end{itemize}
%% use me when using `array' and `ragged2e'
%% but unfortunately this creates a spurious blank line after the `tabitem'
%% environment
%\begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}*{2}{P{4cm}}}
%
% therefore here the solution without these packages
\begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}*{2}{p{4cm}}}
        \toprule
             & \textcolor{green}{Advantages}
             & \textcolor{red}{Disadvantages}                        \\
        \midrule
    Symbolic & \begin{tabitem}
                   \item Analytical solutions
                   \item Lets you intuit things about solution form
               \end{tabitem}
             & \begin{tabitem}
                   \item Sometimes can't be solved
                   \item Can be overly complicated
               \end{tabitem}                                         \\
        \midrule
    Numeric  & \begin{tabitem}
                   \item Always get a solution
                   \item Can make solutions accurate
                   \item Easy to code
               \end{tabitem}
             & \begin{tabitem}
                   \item Hard to extract a deep understanding
                   \item Num.\ methods sometimes fail
                   \item Can take a while to compute
               \end{tabitem}                                         \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]